# How to deal with categorical variables in decision tree when we are passing categorical variables and calling predict function

Tags: python, decision-tree

```
defpredict_career(Problem_Solving_Skill,Analytical_Ability,Maths_Score_12th,Logical_Reasoning,Social_Responsibility,Maths_score_12th,NATA_Score,Interest_in_Biology_subject,Thinking_Reasoning_Skills,Negotiation_Skill,Number_Of_Design_Language,Expansive_Thinking,Assurity_About_Work,Nift_Exam_Score,Typography_Skill,Score_12th,Critical_Thinking_Skill,NEET_Score,Experimental_skill,Communication_Skill,PCM_percentage_12th,Coding_skills,Score_12th_Sci,Diagnostic_skill,Understanding_scientific_literature,score_12th_Science,able_to_do_Mental_calculation,interpret_prescriptions_accurately,Ready_to_take_care_of_animals,Do_you_like_animals,selfless_concern_for_the_wellbeing_of_others,Good_Verbal_Communication,Team_Player,Preference_Technical_Management,Continuous_Learning,Patience_person,memory_skills,Budget_for_Graduation,Interest_research_field,do_work_in_Team,Self_learning_capability):
            x=np.zeros(len(X.columns))
            x[0]=Problem_Solving_Skill
            x[1]=Analytical_Ability
            x[2]=Maths_Score_12th
            x[3]=Logical_Reasoning
            x[4]=Social_Responsibility
            x[5]=Maths_score_12th
            x[6]=NATA_Score
            x[7]=Interest_in_Biology_subject
            x[8]=Thinking_Reasoning_Skills
            x[9]=Negotiation_Skill
            x[10]=Number_Of_Design_Language 
            x[11]=Expansive_Thinking
            x[12]=Assurity_About_Work
            x[13]=Nift_Exam_Score
            x[14]=Typography_Skill
            x[15]=Score_12th
            x[16]=Critical_Thinking_Skill
            x[17]=NEET_Score
            x[18]=Experimental_skill
            x[19]=Communication_Skill
            x[20]=PCM_percentage_12th
            x[21]=Coding_skills
            x[22]=Score_12th_Sci
            x[23]=Diagnostic_skill
            x[24]=Understanding_scientific_literature
            x[25]=score_12th_Science
            x[26]=able_to_do_Mental_calculation
            x[27]=interpret_prescriptions_accurately
            x[28]=Ready_to_take_care_of_animals
            x[29]=Do_you_like_animals
            x[30]=selfless_concern_for_the_wellbeing_of_others
            x[31]=Good_Verbal_Communication
            x[32]=Team_Player
            x[33]=Preference_Technical_Management
            x[34]=Continuous_Learning
            x[35]=Patience_person
            x[36]=memory_skills
            x[37]=Budget_for_Graduation
            x[38]=Interest_research_field
            x[39]=do_work_in_Team
            x[40]=Self_learning_capability
        return dt.predict([x])[0]
```

`predict_career(8,7,83,8,6,81,89,9,9,8,4,8,8,60,5,71,1,555,9,7,78,9,80,6,6,80,'Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Technical','No','No','No','Upto 1 Lakh','Yes','Yes','Yes')`

```
    error:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-23-9d14ae182888> in <module>
    ----> 1 predict_career(8,7,83,8,6,81,89,9,9,8,4,8,8,60,5,71,1,555,9,7,78,9,80,6,6,80,'Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Technical','No','No','No','Upto 1 Lakh','Yes','Yes','Yes')
    
    <ipython-input-22-c44fec6e90b8> in predict_career(Problem_Solving_Skill, Analytical_Ability, Maths_Score_12th, Logical_Reasoning, Social_Responsibility, Maths_score_12th, NATA_Score, Interest_in_Biology_subject, Thinking_Reasoning_Skills, Negotiation_Skill, Number_Of_Design_Language, Expansive_Thinking, Assurity_About_Work, Nift_Exam_Score, Typography_Skill, Score_12th, Critical_Thinking_Skill, NEET_Score, Experimental_skill, Communication_Skill, PCM_percentage_12th, Coding_skills, Score_12th_Sci, Diagnostic_skill, Understanding_scientific_literature, score_12th_Science, able_to_do_Mental_calculation, interpret_prescriptions_accurately, Ready_to_take_care_of_animals, Do_you_like_animals, selfless_concern_for_the_wellbeing_of_others, Good_Verbal_Communication, Team_Player, Preference_Technical_Management, Continuous_Learning, Patience_person, memory_skills, Budget_for_Graduation, Interest_research_field, do_work_in_Team, Self_learning_capability)
         46     x[24]=Understanding_scientific_literature
         47     x[25]=score_12th_Science
    ---> 48     x[26]=able_to_do_Mental_calculation
         49     x[27]=interpret_prescriptions_accurately
         50     x[28]=Ready_to_take_care_of_animals
    
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary categorical variables can be mapped to 0 and 1. For categorical variables of more than 2 categories, you can use one hot encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the string values as numbers.

If using the scikit-learn library, you then need to create an instance of a decision tree class and train your model before making predictions.

You might want to do some research on machine learning and statistics first.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Scikit-Learn class to handle categorical data, the LabelEncoder which is specially designed for handling categorical variables.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(['Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Technical','No','No','No','Upto 1 Lakh','Yes','Yes','Yes'])
le.transform(['Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Technical','No','No','No','Upto 1 Lakh','Yes','Yes','Yes'])
```

This automatically encodes them into numbers for your DT algorithm.

If you want to go back to strings from integers. You can do this by simply calling

> inverse_transform

as follows:

```
list(le.inverse_transform([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,1,1,1]))
```

Also you can use one hot encoder [onehote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) to covert categorical variable to numerical for other ML classifiers.